# Firestore: set post id

Tags: google-cloud-firestore

How can I set id of post that I'm adding? I thought that `getItemNextKey()` returns id that will be assigned for the post, but it's not.

```js
AddItem(data, downloadURLs) {
    data.id= this.getItemNextKey(); // Persist a document id
    data.upload = downloadURLs;
    // console.log('this.uploadService.downloadURLs: ' + downloadURLs);
    // console.log('data.upload: ' + data.upload);

    this.db.collection('items').add(data);
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

I did this and it works now.

```js
// Add a new document with a generated id
    var addDoc = this.db.collection('items').add(data).then(ref => {
      var updateNested = this.db.collection('items').doc(ref.id).update({
        id: ref.id
      });
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

As stated in the official [docs](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/add-data)

> When you use set() to create a document, you must specify an ID for
>   the document to create. For example:

```
db.collection("cities").doc("new-city-id").set(data);
```

If you dont want to set an ID yourself you can use `add`

> But sometimes there isn't a meaningful ID for the document, and it's
>   more convenient to let Cloud Firestore auto-generate an ID for you.
>   You can do this by calling add():